# "substring not found" even though it's included in the argument passed on the command line

Tags: python, ubuntu

I can't figure out why this is happening, so any help is appreciated.

hi.py

```
import httplib, urlparse, sys, urllib

url = sys.argv[1]

print url
print url.index("token")
print url.index("&user")
```

Then in ubuntu if I try to run something like:

```
python hi.py http://somewebsite.com/api?token=hello_world&user=myself
```

I get this as output:

```
http://somewebsite.com/api?token=hello_world
27
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hi.py", line 10, in <module>
    print url.index("&user")
ValueError: substring not found
```

For some reason the whole URL is not being printed, and I suspect that's why the &user substring is not found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is a shell meta character, which [puts the command in the background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line). You need to *quote* your argument to prevent the `&` character from being interpreted as such:

```sh
python hi.py "http://somewebsite.com/api?token=hello_world&user=myself"
```

or use a `\` backslash to escape just the ampersand:

```sh
python hi.py http://somewebsite.com/api?token=hello_world\&user=myself
```

otherwise the shell sees this as two separate commands, with `user=myself` by coincidence being valid shell syntax.

Any of the following characters are [special in a shell](http://www.vias.org/linux-knowhow/lnag_05_05_09.html):

```sh
 \ ' " ` < > | ; <Space> <Tab> <Newline> ( ) [ ] ? # $ ^ & * =
```

These need to be escaped in the same way; the `?` happens to work for the URL since no filenames are being matched; had you used `hi.p?` the filename `hi.py` would be substituted. The `=` only needs escaping when the left-hand side is a valid shell variable identifier I think, but to be safe I'd stick with quoting the whole URL.